# Is it possible to Replace CTE and SELECT with just single sql query (dependent results)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query. Given productid as input (2,4,5) i want to get keyid associate with that list. Then i want to get all products associated with that keyids.

For example:
suppose i am passing productid as 2,4,5 as input to my sproc, i will get keyids as 22,34,35,38 (CTE result). This keys are mapped to the input productlist. Based on this keys (CTE result) i want all the products associated to this keys. Say the keyid = 22 will now have product names with product id as 2,4,5,89 &  keyid = 34 will now have products associated to 2,4,5,23,45 etc.

I came up with the following solution for the above problem. I am just hoping whether we could somehow improve this solution or do this job in single query as two tables are getting repeated.

```
WITH GetKey_CTE
AS 
(
   SELECT k.id, some other select statements
   FROM KeyDim k
        INNER JOIN KeyData kd on kd.id = k.id
        INNER JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm on kpm.id = k.id and kpm.mkey = k.mkey
        INNER JOIN Products p on p.productid = kpm.productid 
                         and p.productid IN (2,4,5)
        LEFT JOIN some more joins 
   WHERE clause conditions
)

SELECT cte.id as keyid, pn.productname, some other columns
FROM GetKey_CTE cte
INNER JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm on cte.id = kpm.id
INNER JOIN Products pn on pn.productid = kpm.productid
ORDER BY cte.id
```

Dataset Example for products and productkeymapping tables :

For Products table:

```
productid name
1         car
2         bike
3         plane
4         bus
5         train
45        cycle
```

ProductKeyMapping table

```
productid    keyid
1             23
2             987
45            23
1             56
```

say input productid is 1, then final result should be:

```
keyid    productid   name
23        1           car
23        45          cycle
56        1           car
```

Comment: Without a better understanding of the schema (entities and relationships), we can't tell if it's possible to avoid two references to the `KeyProductsMapping` and `Products` tables. (A common table expression isn't strictly necessary. That same query could appear as an inline view, and given that the cte (or inline view)  query it doesn't include a GROUP BY, it's likely that it doesn't need to a separate SELECT. Likely the query could re-written with a single SELECT but that query  would have the same table references...  two references to the `Products` and `KeyProductsMapping` tables.

Comment: Makes no sense to me:  INNER JOIN Products pn on cte.productid = kpm.productid

Comment: mymistake , i will update that, the relation is with mapping table

Comment: its pn.productid = kpm.productid and mapping table has relation with keyid

Answer (score 1):

just looking at the data and that simple example

```
select pm2.*, product.name 
  from productmapping pm1 
  join productmapping pm2
         on pm2.keyid = pm1.keyid 
        and pm1.productid in (1) 
  join product 
         on product.id = pm2.productid


declare @product table(id int, name varchar(20));
declare @map table(productid int, keyid int);
insert into @product values 
(1, 'car'),
(2, 'bike'),
(3, 'plane'),
(4, 'bus'),
(5, 'train'),
(45, 'cycle');
insert into @map values 
(1, '23'),
(2, '987'),
(45, '23'),
(1, '56');
select pm2.*, p.name 
  from @map pm1 
  join @map pm2
         on pm2.keyid = pm1.keyid 
        and pm1.productid in (1) 
  join @product p 
         on p.id = pm2.productid
order by pm2.keyid;
```

Comment: self join worked.
For my actual query i used left join.
First to get keyid for productidlist then left  join again for matching key ids

Answer (score 0):

you can also done by using sub query

```
SELECT * FROM KeyProductMapping km 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT k.id, some other select statements
   FROM KeyDim k
        INNER JOIN KeyData kd ON kd.id = k.id
        INNER JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm ON kpm.id = k.id AND kpm.mkey = k.mkey
        INNER JOIN Products p ON p.productid = kpm.productid 
                         AND p.productid IN (2,4,5)
        LEFT JOIN some more joins 
   WHERE clause conditions) AS p ON p.id = km.id
INNER JOIN Products pn ON p.productid = km.productid
ORDER BY cte.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the CTE with an inline view like below but note sure why you are duplicating the JOINS again. Can you post some sample data along with your desired result to look further.

```
SELECT cte.id AS keyid, pn.productname, some other columns
FROM (
   SELECT k.id, some other select statements
   FROM KeyDim k
        INNER JOIN KeyData kd ON kd.id = k.id
        INNER JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm ON kpm.id = k.id AND kpm.mkey = k.mkey
        INNER JOIN Products p ON p.productid = kpm.productid 
                         AND p.productid IN (2,4,5)
        LEFT JOIN some more joins 
   WHERE clause conditions ) cte
INNER JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm ON cte.id = kpm.id
INNER JOIN Products pn ON cte.productid = kpm.productid
ORDER BY cte.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cte.id as keyid, pn.productname, some other columns
FROM ( SELECT k.id, some other select statements
         FROM KeyDim k
         JOIN KeyData kd 
                 on kd.id = k.id
         JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm 
                 on kpm.id = k.id 
                and kpm.mkey = k.mkey
         JOIN Products p 
                 on p.productid = kpm.productid 
                and p.productid IN (2,4,5)
         LEFT JOIN some more joins 
        WHERE clause conditions
     )  CTE
  JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm 
         on cte.id = kpm.id
  JOIN Products pn 
         on pn.productid = kpm.productid
ORDER BY cte.id
```

Above you you query with the CTE in line (a subquery)

A lot of stuff does not make sense to me

```
JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm 
       on kpm.id = k.id 
      and kpm.mkey = k.mkey
JOIN Products p 
       on p.productid = kpm.productid 
      and p.productid IN (2,4,5)
```

is the same as

```
JOIN KeyProductMapping kpm 
       on kpm.id = k.id 
      and kpm.mkey = k.mkey
      and p.productid IN (2,4,5)
```

unless product does not have those values

why

```
SELECT k.id, some other select statements
  FROM KeyDim k
  JOIN KeyData kd 
         on kd.id = k.id
```

same as

```
SELECT kd.id   -- move this to main select, some other select statements
FROM KeyData kd
```

why?

```
LEFT JOIN some more joins
```

move that to main statement

Comment: Hi Paparazzi, from other joins also i need some value thats why 'more joins'. About kpm.mkey = k.mkey, you can skip this part, actually there is one more table in joins which i have not mentioned. so its key table -> keyfact -> productkeymap -> product chain. My main focus is on using all table only once to reduce join combinations.

Comment: but get other values you need in main query

Comment: yes i was actually using cte values, say cte.col1, cte.col2 in my main query.
the keydim table is associated with many joins so i kept it in cte. but still i can move those joins to main query and reference those joins with cte. i agree with that point.

Comment: It is just confusing to carry output data around like that.  Reduce the CTE to the mapping only.